# How to enable debugging in x64 mode in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, 64-bit

I am using OpenCv 64-bit in visual studio 2013.
when I opened configuration manager and I changed platform to x64 , debugging has became disabled and I can't debug my code .
Anybody knows how I can enable debugging in x64 mode ?

Comment: would you mind letting me know that latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you use the 64 bit machine, please also make sure that you use the correct steps to config the Environment.

For detailed steps, please see this video:

[Installing OpenCV with Visual Studio 2013, and Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNlnjBLPJd8)